# Add 90 degrees to a Quaternion in Away3d

Tags: actionscript-3, math, quaternions, away3d

I'm attempting to rotate a Quaternion up 90 degrees on the Y axis in Away3d.  I'm using an ANE to get Quaternion values from device motion, to set the camera view.

This rotates the angle up,

```
            qu.fromAxisAngle(Vector3D.X_AXIS,Math.PI/2);
            q.multiply(q, qu );
```

But then seems to switch the other angles, i.e. now panning the device rolls the view.

Comment: If I understand your comment, you want to rotate around Y (let's call this pitch), and if I understand your code, you're effectively rotating around X (let's call this roll). Do i understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the order worked

q.multiply(qu, q );